# Where are the Joker Balloons in Amusement Row?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've been up and down Amusement Row in *Batman: Arkham City* and I have only found 3 or so Joker Balloons. Do I need to progress further in the story for them to spawn or are they just waiting inside a building?

> I'm tracing the Joker's radio signal to the steel mill.

Comment: There's definitely more than three scattered around outside, and not sure there are any inside. Haven't come across any good guides though for them, they are just around on buildlings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed that more will spawn later in the game.

> Specifically, more spawned after I emerged from the ruins of Old Gotham after the encounter with Rāʾs al Ghūl. At this point in the story Joker took the territory from the Penguin.